# If process1 isn't running start process2

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a script that launches process1 which spawns process2, then wait for process2 to exit and launch process3.

Sounds pretty simple to me but I can't get it to work at all.

I tried searching for a similar solution and found something like this

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq process1"
if errorlevel 0 (
        echo "1"
    exit 0
) else (
    echo "2"
    exit 0

)
```

but even something this simple spawns around 1000 shells and then crashes

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here but I can't find out what.

Comment: did you name your file `tasklist.bat or tasklist.cmd`? if yes, it is calling itself again and again. rename it or enter full path for tasklist.exe

Comment: @elzooilogico yeah, I did, such a dumb mistake.

Comment: welcome to the 'yes, I couldn't imagine myself doing such a thing' club. or drink one more cup of coffee in the morning, C(_)

Comment: Please don't append solutions to questions, post them as answers instead! you may even [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

So, I was doing something wrong as pointed out by @elzooilogico - for some reason I named it tasklist.bat and it called itself.

My script looks like this and works like a charm

```
start process1.lnk
timeout /t 50
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq process2.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "process2.exe">NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    start process3
) else (
    timeout /t 5
    goto loop
)
```

It launches process1, waits for 50 second and then exits if it process2 doesn't exist anymore or loops in 5 second intervals until process2 exits. When it finally does it launches process3.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem would seem to be that your interpretation of `if errorlevel 0` is different from `cmd`'s interpretation.

`if errorlevel n` is interpreted by `cmd` as "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**"

Hence, `if errorlevel 0` is essentially **always true** (there are some esoteric circumstance where `errorlevel` becomes negative).

Solution: Easiest is probably `if %errorlevel%==0`
Another choice : `if errorlevel 1 (the "else" part from your code) else (the TRUE part of your code)`

Answer (score 0):

`start` has a `/wait` switch that tells batch to start a program and not continue the script until it completes.

```
start "" /wait process1
start "" /wait process2
start "" /wait process3
```

Comment: It won't really work because I can't run process2 - it's launched automatically by process1. Process1 is a launcher and you can't bypass it